# Initial loading of UISegmentedControl does nothing until a segment is clicked?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` where each segment loads a `UIScrollView`.

For some reason, when the view is initially loaded, the first segment is highlighted but the scroll view is not. In order to load it I must go to segment 2 and then back to 1...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that whatever action you have attached to the segmented control doesn't get fired when the control has its initial state set. You'll probably have to call that method manually when the view loads.